# xlOLELinks in a loop do not update (vba, excel)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to import to excel data from a OLE source using xlOLELinks links. My code runs just fine under debug mode or using breakpoints, but if I run it non-stop  links do not always update and I get a

> type mismatch error (Run-time error 13).

I already tried making active my spreadsheet, redundant link updates, different ways to write the same code but I can't figure it out...   Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
  'Links missing the index and to be completed in the loop
  TimeStr = "DM|Dictionary!JDP_TIME."
  PressureStr = "DM|Dictionary!JDP_TRTPRESS."
  RateStr = "DM|Dictionary!JDP_SLRYRATE."
  Worksheets("Data").Activate

  Row = 1
  While Not ExitFlag
    'Link + index
    ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:=TimeStr & CStr(Row - 1), Type:=xlOLELinks
    ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:=PressureStr & CStr(Row - 1), Type:=xlOLELinks
    ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:=RateStr & CStr(Row - 1), Type:=xlOLELinks

    'Transfering the values to a table
    Cells(Row + 1, 1) = Cells(1, 9)
    Cells(Row + 1, 2) = Cells(1, 10)
    Cells(Row + 1, 3) = Cells(1, 11)

    'Updating the links
    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=TimeStr & CStr(Row - 1), _
                          NewName:=TimeStr & CStr(Row), _
                          Type:=xlOLELinks
    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=PressureStr & CStr(Row - 1), _
                          NewName:=PressureStr & CStr(Row), _
                          Type:=xlOLELinks
    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=RateStr & CStr(Row - 1), _
                          NewName:=RateStr & CStr(Row), _
                          Type:=xlOLELinks

    'Updating the index for the next set of data
    Row = Row + 1

    ' If the last value in column A is zero, break the loop
    LRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(LRow, 1) = 0 Then ExitFlag = True
  Wend


    'Resets links to the initial values
    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=TimeStr & CStr(Row - 1), _
                          NewName:=TimeStr & "0", _
                          Type:=xlOLELinks
    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=PressureStr & CStr(Row - 1), _
                          NewName:=PressureStr & "0", _
                          Type:=xlOLELinks
    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=RateStr & CStr(Row - 1), _
                          NewName:=RateStr & "0", _
                          Type:=xlOLELinks
```

so...

This is what I get:

```
|   A  |   B  |   C  |
|    1 | 14.9 |   80 |
|    2 |   20 | #N/A |
| #N/A | #N/A | #N/A |
```

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: If Cells(LRow, 1) = 0 Then ExitFlag = True

Comment: the error pops up because the cell has a #n/A (the link didn't bring the value)

Comment: I've been doing some research and seems like the problem is effectively that the links do not update in time. The link info is a task performed by the OS (Windows in this case) and as soon as the macro invokes the update link command, the macro moves on to the next command without waiting on the OS to finish its process.

I have tried a few work arounds without success so far (DoEvents, disabling the background query and forcing a refresh) but nothing helps...